# Reversed parentheses in acro when compiling with Xelatex

Tags: xetex, bidi, acro

Parentheses are  reversed in acro   when compiling with Xelatex.

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{
    list/sort = true , % <==============================================
%   page-style = comma , % <========================== removed from acro
%   extra-style = paren , % <========================= removed from acro
%list/display = all,
    make-links = true  % <==============================================
}
\DeclareAcronym{CDMA}{
    short            = CDMA ,
    long             = Code Division Multiple Access ,
    long-plural      = es,
    tag= foo % <========================================================
}
\DeclareAcronym{GSM}{
    short            = GSM ,
    long             = Global System for Mobile communication,
    tag= foo % <========================================================
}
\DeclareAcronym{NA}{
    short            = {\ensuremath{N_{\mathrm{A}}}} ,
    long             = Number of Avogadro ,
    extra            = see \S\ref{Chem} ,
    pdfstring        = NA,
    tag= foo
}
\DeclareAcronym{NAD+}{
    short            = {NAD\textsuperscript{+}} ,
    short-plural     = ,
    long             = Nicotinamide Adenine Dinucleotide ,
    pdfstring        = NAD+ ,
    tag= baz
}
\DeclareAcronym{NUA}{
    short            = NUA ,
    long             = Not Used Acronym,
    tag= baz
}
\DeclareAcronym{TDMA}{
    short            = TDMA ,
    long             = Time Division Multiple Access ,
    long-plural      = es,
    extra = reverse parentheses ,
    tag= baz
}
\DeclareAcronym{UA}{
    short            = UA ,
    long             = Used Acronym,
    tag= baz
}
\DeclareAcronym{lox}{
    short            = {\emph{LOX}} ,
    long             = Liquid Oxygen ,
    pdfstring        = LOX,
    tag= baz
}
\DeclareAcronym{lh2}{
    short            = {\emph{LH\textsubscript{2}}} ,
    long             = Liquid Hydrogen ,
    pdfstring        = LH2,
    tag= baz
}
\DeclareAcronym{IC}{
    short            = IC ,
    long             = Integrated Circuit,
    extra = Blocks Under Test ,
    tag= baz
}
\DeclareAcronym{BUT}{
    short            = BUT ,
    long             = Block Under Test ,
    long-plural-form = Blocks Under Test ,
    extra = Blocks Under Test ,
    tag= baz
}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1.3]{Amiri}
\setlatintextfont[Scale=1.3]{Arial}
\defpersianfont\Sayeh[Scale=1.5]{Arial}


\begin{document}
\printacronyms[name=Foo,include=foo]
\printacronyms[name=Baz,include=baz]
\newpage
\acs{GSM}
\ac{TDMA}
\acs{GSM}
\ac{CDMA}    
\ac{TDMA}
\ac{GSM} 
\acs{GSM}\ac{GSM}\ac{TDMA}.
\ac{CDMA}\acs{GSM}
 \acs{GSM} \ac{TDMA}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The next screenshot shows the result with `acro v2.11d`, text in RTL language is with `extra = ....,` in `\acsetup`. i want to remove the parenthees from the list.
[image]

```
 \DeclareAcronym{auc}{
  short = AUC,
  long = Area Under the ROC Curve ,
  %foreign = Geographical Information System ,
  %foreign-lang = english,
  extra = \hfill \rl{المساحة تحت منحنى "روك``},
  class = abbrev
}
```

Comment: Your output shows the TDMA's expansion "Time Division Multiple Access" going backwards from right to left, which suggests to me you are in some sort of right-to-left language set up? I suspect this may be caused by the `xepersian` package, but I don't know anything about it.

Comment: The main language is Persian, then the RTL text is fine, the only issue is the parentheses. is there a way to exclude them from acro?

Comment: Can you show a mock-up of what the desired output should be?

Comment: Why are you using xepersian when your main language is Arabic?

Comment: @user I mean RTL language, it could be Arabic, Persian or Hebrew ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current `acro` list templates have the brackets immediately preceding/following the printing of the extra key (e.g. https://github.com/cgnieder/acro/blob/9a56e414b0eb82ff89241decc66da9620f2292df/code/acro.definitions.code.tex#L195-L216).
This means that `(reverse parentheses)` is produced and while I'm not familiar with `xepersian`/RTL typesetting, the problem appears to be that this is typeset in two parts: `(reverse` then `parentheses)`.
If we instead insert a zero-width space, things seem to get typeset in the right order (with the brackets seen separately to the extra text), which we can do defining a new style based on the existing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\NewAcroTemplate[list]{descriptionRTL}{%
\acroheading
\acropreamble
\begin{description}
\acronymsmapF{%
\item[\acrowrite{short}\acroifT{alt}{/\acrowrite{alt}}]
\acrowrite{list}%
\acroifanyT{foreign,extra}{ (\hspace{0pt}}%
\acroifT{foreign}{\acrowrite{foreign}\acroifT{extra}{, }}%
\acroifT{extra}{\acrowrite{extra}}%
\acroifanyT{foreign,extra}{\hspace{0pt})}%
\acropagefill
\acropages
{\acrotranslate{page}\nobreakspace}
{\acrotranslate{pages}\nobreakspace}%
}
{\item\AcroRerun}
\end{description}
}

\acsetup{
list/template=descriptionRTL
}

\DeclareAcronym{TDMA}{
    short            = TDMA ,
    long             = Time Division Access ,
    long-plural      = es,
    %foreign = bar,
    extra = reverse parentheses ,
    tag= baz
}

\usepackage{xepersian}

\settextfont[Scale=1.3]{Amiri}
\setlatintextfont[Scale=1.3]{Arial}
\defpersianfont\Sayeh[Scale=1.5]{Arial}

\begin{document}
\printacronyms

\ac{TDMA}
\end{document}
```

Where the only changes from the normal `description` list template are addding `\hspace{0pt}` to the lines `\acroifanyT{foreign,extra}{ (\hspace{0pt}}%` and `\acroifanyT{foreign,extra}{\hspace{0pt})}%`.

[image: Image of compiled document. Text which is in RTL reads: Acronyms (parentheses reverse) Access Division Time TDMA (TDMA) Access Division Time]

There may well be a better way to do bracketing within `xepersian` etc, if so modifying the list template as above is the way to implement this within `acro`.